# How to make ActionBar tabs always display narrow mode on tablets (In portrait mode)?

Tags: android

I have an application that I am supporting for both tablets and mobile devices that both use a tabbed design (using ActionBar tabs).  On my mobile device the tabs work fine, however on my tablet the tabs get automatically put into the ActionBar. The devices are only in portrait mode, I am not supporting landscape.

Is there anyway I can not have the tabs go into the ActionBar on my tablet and make them appear like normal tabs?

Comment: If you don't want tabs in the action bar, you should not be "using ActionBar tabs", since the point of "using ActionBar tabs" is to have tabs in the action bar.

Comment: I see your point I just didn't want to use the deprecated TabWidget pattern (At least the android devs suggest not to use it). I wanted to keep a universal design for my tabs for portrait mode in for both phones and tablets. I guess I am going to have to implement some forking logic to determine if i am on a tablet vs phone.

Comment: btw im a huge fan of your work :)

Comment: If you happen to be using `ViewPager`, `PagerTabStrip` (or the tab equivalent from the ViewPagerIndicator library) looks a lot like "tabs that are technically in the action bar but got put beneath the bar in portrait mode", which I am guessing is what you're aiming for. I am not aware of a general-purpose `TabWidget` replacement that shares the `PagerTabStrip` look and does not have the limitations on action bar tabs. "btw im a huge fan of your work" -- thanks!